# convert decimal to string without removing 0 "zero(s)"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
nStr    =   12.00;
alert(typeof(nStr));// getting number
x = nStr.split('.');
// Other than string Split function Through an error,
nStr    =   12.00;
nStr    +=  '';
alert(typeof(nStr));// getting string
x       =   nStr.split('.');
x1      =   x[0];
x2      =   x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
alert(x1+x2);

//Expected Output is 12.00
```

I got the temp output coding ( its not optimized coding)

```
nStr += '';
x = nStr.split('.');
x1  = x[0];
x[1]= (x[1].length == 1) ? '.' + x[1] + '0' : '.' + x[1];
x2  = x.length > 1 ? x[1] : '.00';
alert(x1+x2);               //  12.00
```

Comment: You're looking for a equilivant of printf(). This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

12.00 **is** 12 you can't change that fact.

Looks like what you are after is the `toFixed()` method of JavaScript:

```
nStr    =   12;
alert(nStr.toFixed(2));
```

This will alert "12.00" as you want. The number passed to the method determines how many digits after the decimal point will be displayed.

Worth mentioning is that the `toFixed` method will also round numbers, for example if in the above example `nStr` will be 12.5283 it will show 12.53 in the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing

```
nStr    =   12.00;
```

u can write something like this

```
nStr    =   "12.00";
```